# Custom xkb layout on Ubuntu 21.04 Wayland

Tags: wayland, xkb

I have googled various guides on creating a custom keyboard layout using xkb. I want the left alt key to send a control key event. After lots of trial and error I came up with this (based on Estonian keyboard layout):

```
partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "ee_dfv" {
    include "ee(basic)"

    name[Group1]="Estonian (DFV)";

    key <LALT> {
        type[Group1]="ONE_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1] = [ Control_L ]
    };

    modifier_map Control { <LALT> };
};
```

I added it to `evdev.xml` and when I use the GNOME layout visualiser it does show the modified mapping but the keys work as before. Surprisingly the modified mapping works correctly in xterm.

Am I doing something wrong or is there another way of modifying the keyboard layout with Wayland? I successfully used xmodmap for a decade but googling suggests it's not supported by Wayland.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: There's an excellent program called [xremap](https://github.com/k0kubun/xremap) which works with both X and Wayland. The configuration format is even simpler than xmodmap in my opinion and it also supports application-specific remapping.